# django at extra_context 'unicode' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, django

I have this model admin class where I need to add an extra variable for my custom template:

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def change_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        print extra_context
        extra_context["show_save_as_draft"] = True
        return super(ArticleAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)
```

While testing it I hit this error:

```
TypeError at /admin/news/article/4/
'unicode' object does not support item assignment
```

In trace back, I got this following:

```
/home/sadaf2605/PycharmProjects/stripe/stripe/news/admin.py in change_view
        extra_context["show_save_as_draft"] = True ...
▼ Local     vars
Variable    Value
self    <news.admin.ArticleAdmin object at 0x7f2ad3eb21d0>
extra_context   u'4'
```

as we can see `extra_context` is called with 4 here, how should I treat this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the correct signature for the change_view method. It should be:

```
def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
```

You've missed out the object_id param, so the value (4)  is going into extra_context instead.

Remember to update your super call as well.

Answer (score 0):

> please check the super method call, you define a method 
>   change_view,but in super you specified changelist_view, so there is a 
>   mismatched function calls

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
def change_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    extra_context = extra_context or {}
    print extra_context
    extra_context["show_save_as_draft"] = True
    return super(ArticleAdmin, self).change_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)
```

> Also look into this [click here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_view)